# Android multiple PDP support

Tags: android, pdp

Does android support multiple PDP contexts?

From Gingerbread Telephony package, I can understand that single PDP can only be created and active at one time.

i.e. PDP_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE = 1

From which Android version, multiple PDP contexts will be supported?

Answer (score 0):

android does not support multiple pdp , but the vendors all support it.